# Mittag-Leffler condition for De Rham complexes

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I am currently looking at a proof of De Rham's theorem.

Denote by $\Omega^p(M)$ the space of $p$-forms. At some point, one considers a manifold $M=\bigcup U_i$ where each $U_i$ is an open subset, such that $U_i\subset U_{i+1}$ and $\overline{U_i}$ is compact.
Then by considering the inclusion maps $U_i \to U_{i+1}$, for any $p$ their pullbacks make $(\Omega^p(U_i))_{i}$ into an inverse system. This system satisfies the Mittag-Leffler condition, that is to say that for any integer $n$, there is an integer $m\geq n$ such that for any $i\geq m$, we have $$\mathrm{Im}(\Omega^p(U_i)\to \Omega^p(U_n))=\mathrm{Im}(\Omega^p(U_m)\to \Omega^p(U_n))$$

My question is: why is it true that it satisfies the Mittag-Leffler condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try $m=n+1$. It suffices to prove that if $\omega$ is a smooth form on $U_{n+1}$
then  there's a smooth form $\omega'$
on $M$ whose restriction to $U_n$ is the same as that of $\omega$.

Let $K=\overline{U_n}$. Then $K$ is a compact subset of $U_{n+1}$ and indeed of $M$.
There is a smooth "bump function" $\phi:M\to\Bbb R$ which equals $1$ on $K$
and has compact support contained in $U_{n+1}$. Then $\phi\omega$ is well-defined
on $U_{n+1}$, it has compact support, and restricts to $\omega$ on $U_n$. We can
extend $\phi\omega$ by zero to a form on all of $M$ with these same properties.
Then we can take $\omega'$ to be this extension.